# How to inspect which values were used in calculation in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

In cases where I have complicated formulas like

```
=HLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN((D$165-1)/12,0)+1,$D$24:$M$25,2)*D$2
```

Is there a good way to see which values ended up being used in the calculation? In this case, I would be looking for something like

```
13000*0.04
```

where 13000 is the result of

```
=HLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN((D$165-1)/12,0)+1,$D$24:$M$25,2)
```

and 0.04 is the result of

```
D$2
```

It would also be great to be able to see the result for each function so in this case I could see the value of

```
=ROUNDDOWN((D$165-1)/12,0)
```

I'm imagining some functionality where I hover above each section of the calculation to "inspect" it. Any ideas?

FYI - I am using Excel for Mac 2011.

Here is an example of what this looks like with nested functions. Note that you cannot see the detailed breakout of the bottom "if statement":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Select the cell containing the formula.
2. Go to the Tab "Formulas" and look for "Evaluate formula" and click it:

   [image]

A dialog box where you can make step by step evaluation of the formula will appear. This should be what you're looking for.

I have Excel 2007 for Windows, but I'm pretty sure the MAC version should have it as well.

Comment: Same thing on Excel for Mac 2011. It is located under "Formulas" bar, and click on Formula Builder. As @Jerry said above, it will show a window with all the formulas listed, and show the result of each individual formulas. Oh and edited to add: You can also use the Trace Dependants / Trace Precedents to check where are the cells responsible for the content of the formula (the cells used in the formula will be tagged, rather than trying to find the cell D165, there will be a line, and special box for D165)

Comment: In windows you can also select any coherent part of the formula in the formula bar and press F9 key - the result of that specific part of the formula is now displayed in the formula bar in place of the part highlighted

Comment: This is helpful, thanks guys. Any idea how to see nested functions? I've edited my question above with an example.

Comment: @user531065 Hmm, the Formula Builder is a bit different from Evaluate Formula. Sorry, I'm not sure how to help here :( The windows version evaluates all the formulas from left to right, from the innermost function to the outermost so you see exactly all the steps.

Comment: Excel for Windows has the same formula builder although the GUI is different. It's the `fx` button right next to the formula bar. It works the same way (doesn't show nested function results) and only works if the entire formula is inside a function. For the given example, you'd have to remove the `*D$2` at the end. Otherwise, it just shows the result.